# How does one compute the Euler product for the Dirichlet Beta function?

Tags: proof-explanation, special-functions, euler-product

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327543/does-the-euler-product-for-the-dirichlet-beta-function-converge-for-all-re/2576730) post, the author derives the Euler product for Dirichlet Beta function, defined as

$$\beta(s) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^s}$$

for $\Re(s)>0$ and obtains

$$\beta(s) = \prod_p \bigg(\frac {p^s}{p^s-\sin\left(\frac{p \,\pi}{2}\right)} \bigg).$$

I would like to know how one arrives to the Euler product, can someone show me a proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the author of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327543/does-the-euler-product-for-the-dirichlet-beta-function-converge-for-all-re/2576730) did, using Dirichlet character $\chi:=\chi_4$, we can write $$\displaystyle \beta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}$$ where $$
\chi(n)=\begin{cases}1\ \ \  \text{ for }n\equiv 1\ \text{mod }4\\-1\ \ \ \text{ for }n\equiv 3\ \text{mod }4\\0\ \ \ \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}.
$$ We can see that $\chi(nm)=\chi(n)\chi(m)$ for all $n,m\ge 1$, hence
$$\begin{align*}
\beta(s)&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}\\&=\sum_{r_1,r_2,\cdots\ge 0} \frac{\prod_j \chi(p_j)^{r_j}}{\prod_j p_j^{sr_j}}
\\&=\prod_j \left(1+\frac{\chi(p_j)}{p_j^s} +\frac{\chi(p_j)^2}{p_j^{2s}}+\cdots\right)\\&=\prod_p \frac1{1-p^{-s}\chi(p)}\\&=\prod_p \frac{p^s}{p^s-\chi(p)}=\prod_p \frac{p^s}{p^s-\sin\left(\frac{p\pi}2\right)},
\end{align*}$$ for all $\Re(s)>1$.